# Android Studio only updates changes when It run a second time

Tags: android, android-studio

Every time I bring changes to my code:

1. I need to run the emulator once
2. Then instantly rerun

If I only run once, it still runs the previous code.
Please help me as I would like to configure AS that if I press run once all the changes are accepted the first time.

Comment: Try Re Installing android Emulator

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Android Emulator with another SDK version.
I had the same issue earlier and just created another one emulator.